# I can not return the final date of a range of dates

Tags: php, laravel, function, date, controller

with this code I can get the start date but not the end date

```
$period = new \DatePeriod(new \DateTime($dateStart), new \DateInterval('P1D'), (new \DateTime($dateend)));
```

I am returning a range of dates, but I do not take the last date, in this example I did it with 2 days, I take the first but not the second, which should be 2019-08-05

```
DatePeriod {#448 ▼
  period: every + 1d, from 2019-08-04 00:00:00.0 (included) to 2019-08-05 00:00:00.0
  +"start": DateTime @1564876800 {#468 ▼
    date: 2019-08-04 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)
  }
  +"current": null
  +"end": DateTime @1564963200 {#457 ▶}
  +"interval": DateInterval {#458 ▶}
  +"recurrences": 1
  +"include_start_date": true
}
```

How could the end date be included?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding 1 day to the final day

```
$dateend->modify('+1 day');
$period = new \DatePeriod(new \DateTime($dateStart), new \DateInterval('P1D'), (new \DateTime($dateend)));
```